# In the Chrome browser (in Windows 10) reputation has an issue

Tags: bug, reputation-graph, reputation-history

When I click on the reputation bar, it's not showing the posts from which I got the score. It's happening on Windows 10 OS with the Chrome browser.

[image]

In the developers toolbar no request is happening when I click on the bar:

[image]

Comment: Heh seems like the script that makes that graph do anything is missing. No errors to suggest it's broken, just not running at all.

Comment: Its not running at all